# Why did pip install a package into ~/.local/bin?

Tags: files, software-installation, python, pip, lsb

When I install this "Taurus Blazemeter 'bzt'" program with pip, it ends up being installed into `~/.local/bin`  folder.

```
mkdir ~/bzt && cd ~/bzt
sudo apt-get install python default-jre-headless python-tk python-pip python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo pip install bzt
```

Does anyone  know what use this `~/.local` folder is for and why a Python program like this one would install there?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost  Ok, I updated my question.

Comment: If you want to know when Python uses `~/.local/bin` directory read [PEP 0370 -- Per user site-packages directory](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/).

Comment: Never ever (almost) use `sudo pip (...)` – see [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735), [Is it acceptable & safe to run pip install under sudo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/95735) and [Default to --user](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668) pip's issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is that `~/.local/bin` is the default value of Python's User Script Directory and that `pip` may install executables into this directory if it performs a user-local installation. It may also install files into other subdirectories of `~/.local`, which is the default value of the User Base Directory. More details below.

---

I'm not sure if this is its earliest introduction, but the `~/.local` directory appears in the [file-system hierarchy specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) of the [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) init system, where it defines several subdirectories of `~/.local`:

> **~/.local/bin**
>
> Executables that shall appear in the user's $PATH search path. It is
>   recommended not to place executables in this directory that are not
>   useful for invocation from a shell; these should be placed in a
>   subdirectory of ~/.local/lib instead. Care should be taken when
>   placing architecture-dependent binaries in this place, which might be
>   problematic if the home directory is shared between multiple hosts
>   with different architectures.
>
> **~/.local/lib**
>
> Static, private vendor data that is compatible with all architectures.
>
> **~/.local/lib/arch-id**
>
> Location for placing public dynamic libraries. The architecture
>   identifier to use is defined on Multiarch Architecture Specifiers
>   (Tuples) list.
>
> **~/.local/share**
>
> Resources shared between multiple packages, such as fonts or artwork.
>   Usually, the precise location and format of files stored below this
>   directory is subject to specifications that ensure interoperability.
>   If an application finds $XDG_DATA_HOME set, it should use the
>   directory specified in it instead of this directory.

The adoption of the `~/.local` directory by Python appears to have been introduced in Python 2.6 and is documented in PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal) 370:

- [PEP 370 -- Per user site-packages directory](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)

The specification includes the following definitions for Unix systems (including Mac OS X).

- User Base Directory

  `~/.local`
- User Script Directory:

  `~/.local/bin`
- User Site Directory:

  `~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages`
- User Data Directory:

  `~/.local/lib/python2.6`

From this we can conclude that Python has the concept of a so-called "Base User Directory" and that its default value is `~/.local`. The Base User Directory is discussed in the [Python documentation for the `site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html). In particular, it provides methods for determining the values of your User Base Directory and User Site Directory, the `--user-base` and `--user-site` options flags. You could use them like so:

```bsh
user@host:~$ python -m site --user-base

/home/user/.local

user@host:~$ python -m site --user-site

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

There are several questions posted to StackExchange sites related to the `~/.local` directory which I used as references:

- [Why should I install Python packages into `~/.local`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558145/why-should-i-install-python-packages-into-local)
- [Whats the .local folder for in my Home Directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14535/whats-the-local-folder-for-in-my-home-directory)
- [Why is ~/.local/share a two-level directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1170793/why-is-local-share-a-two-level-directory)
- [Which distributions have $HOME/.local/bin in $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path)
- [Understanding home configuration file locations: ~/, ~/.config/ and ~/.local/share/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312988/understanding-home-configuration-file-locations-config-and-local-sha)
- [user site-package directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013763/user-site-package-directory)
- [What is the simplest way to do a user-local install of a python package?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-a-user-local-install-of-a-python-package)

Comment: I use `~/.local` as my `prefix` for `./configure` for all software I manually compiled from source on clusters where I don't have root permission (well I installed a lot...including `bash` and `coreutils`...the clusters are really old). I have seen others do this but I am not sure how common this practice is.

Comment: @WeijunZhou sounds good but this does not help here where mainly people working with pip as users want to know where the installed pip packages are.