# Have MobaXterm automatically load a local bashrc when connecting to a remote Linux system?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I routinely use Mobaxterm to SSH to the bash shell of various Linux devices to troubleshoot. I don't have my own account, it's a single root account used for the entire system (it's embedded devices), that other people may connect to as well.

I have custom functions and aliases defined in my personal bashrc file, that I'd like to be able to use on those remote systems.

However, I'm not supposed to modify the remote filesystem, or change the default bashrc and aliases other people get when they connect.

I'd like my personal bashrc loaded upon connection, and only apply to my session. Can I achieve this with Mobaxterm?

Comment: This seems like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565396/5132 again.

Comment: @JdeBP, I don't think it is. The linked discussion suggests creating your home environment in a different directory and modifying the session's environment variables to point to that home directory. I can't modify the remote filesystem, because it's not my system. I'm allowed to connect to troubleshoot, that's it. I could transfer files then delete them when done but this is annoying and error-prone.

Comment: I don't know if Mobaxterm can be configured to run commands on the remote system at login and then leave the shell to the user.  You could paste the commands from a file on your own device into Mobaxterm when you are connected.

Comment: So where are you expecting to store this "personal `.bashrc` file", if not in the filesystem?