# Which distributions have $HOME/.local/bin in $PATH?

Tags: path, distributions, xdg

For example, in Ubuntu, there is always a `.local` directory in the home directory and `.profile` includes this line:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

`$HOME/.local/bin` does not exist by default, but if it is created it's already in `$PATH` and executables within can be found.

This is not exactly mentioned in the [XDG directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) but seems derived from it.

What I wonder is if this is common enough that it could be usually assumed to exist in the most common end user distributions. Is it, for instance, in all of the Debian derivatives, or at least the Ubuntu ones? How about the Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS ecosystem? And so on with Arch, SUSE, and what people are using nowadays.

To be extra clear, this is only for `$HOME/.local/bin`, *not* `$HOME/bin`.

Out of curiosity, feel free to include BSDs, OS/X and others if you have the information. :)

Comment: @ThomasDickey also, you say that Fedora does this at the same time as you haven't encountered it on any system, I assume one of those is a typo. Or I misunderstand?

Comment: I don't have it in my path, and I certainly won't put it there. (Debian, but xdm/fvwm, neither Gnome nor KDE as desktop).

Comment: I checked for a system which might have it.  None of my development accounts use **bash**, and packagers simply aren't thorough enough to notice unless I make a special check (see [newpath](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:newpath)).

Comment: IIRC Ubuntu's `/etc/skel/.profile` up to and including at least 14.04 tests for the presence of a user's `$HOME/bin` and adds it to the `PATH` if it exists; in contrast, 16.04 appears to add both `$HOME/bin` and `$HOME/.local/bin` unconditionally. I don't recall earlier Ubuntus adding `$HOME/.local/bin` at all - but I don't see anything relevant in the `bash` package changelog (which supposedly owns `/etc/skel/.profile`).

Comment: @steeldriver thanks. The upside of the unconditional add is that it doesn't really matter if it doesn't exist, but if you install something that adds it it will start to work without restart or re-sourcing of `.profile`. I also remember it as being conditional earlier.

Comment: @steeldriver Interestingly, Ubuntu 17.04 does not have `$HOME/.local/bin` added to `PATH` by default.

Comment: FWIW, none of the BSDs does this.

Comment: TIL Ubuntu (20.04) does have `~/.local/bin` in `/etc/skel/.profile` — but that doesn't help if you version your dot files & re-install them into all new accounts for decades on end. Thus, I've been manually adding it (`PATH=~/.local/bin:"$PATH"`), ever since starting python stuff (initially very surprised that python ecosystem chose to use a hidden `~/.local/` for binaries‍♂️)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The `~/.local` directories are part of [the systemd file-hierarchy spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) and is an extension of the [xdg-user-dirs spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/).

It can be confusing as Debian-derived packages for `bash` lost the `~/.local` path when they rebased to Bash 4.3. They did have it in Bash 4.2.

It is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=839155), and a patch has been sitting in the Debian system for a bit now.

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1588562) is the reason Ubuntu 16.04 had `~/.local` in the path and Ubuntu 17.04 did not.

If you run `systemd-path` as a user, you will see that it is intended to be in the path.

```
$ systemd-path user-binaries
/home/foo/.local/bin
```

In theory, the answer to your query is: *Any distro that uses systemd or wants to maintain compatibility with systemd.*

There is more information in [`file-hierarchy(7)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html).

Comment: Thanks! Out of pure curiosity, was this also the case during upstart times? Only asking because my memory says it was there earlier than systemd, but it's equally likely I just misremember it!

Comment: I'd doubt it was before systemd, forever the convention was ~/bin.

Comment: Arrgh, this bug seems to have also arrived in 16.04 courtesy of a backported bash 4.3

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What about `zsh`?

Comment: Debian Bullseye here – neither `bash` nor `fish` load `~/.local/bin` into `PATH`. I needed to add it manually to `~/.profile` for `bash` and for [`fish`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#path) I added it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34401308/1321680): `set -U fish_user_paths $HOME/.local/bin/ $fish_user_paths`.

Answer (score 8):

On RPM based distributions, the situation seems to look like this:

- RHEL 7 - [does add it to the end of `PATH`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1583227) when you use a login shell. It will work with `sudo su -l johndoe` but it will not work if you do not use the `-l` switch.
- CentOS 7 - see RHEL, it  is always following RHEL.
- Fedora 28 (probably older too) - same as RHEL/CentOS, added to the end of PATH

As for other distributions:

- Arch Linux - currently [does not set the path](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/77447)

If you want to see those bugs sorted, please do not forget to vote/comment on those as this would highlight the importance of the issue.