# Can I somehow skip the run in terminal prompt?

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

Always when I want to execute my script, I need to confirm that I want to run it in terminal. Is there a way to easily skip that, or set this as default?

I am using Nemo file manager (Mint)

Comment: This question is offtopic as it is not about Unix and Linux, but more about your file manager. You might find some help here: https://superuser.com/questions/763554/how-to-make-it-so-bash-runs-instead-of-asking-where-to-run-upon-selection-from-f

Comment: @Panki This question seems fine to me. Users can [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about "Applications packaged in *nix distributions". There's even a tag for `nemo`. I'm not even sure if this is related to nemo, or just the DE itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your executable scripts on the Desktop, create a separate directory for them. Traditionally this has been `$HOME/bin` but [I understand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316765/100397) it's now something like `$HOME/.local/bin`. Either way,  you can also add this directory to your `$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` or other startup file.

As an example, consider an executable script, `$HOME/bin/thing`.

Now, instead of having your executable on the Desktop, you create a launcher. You can do this either graphically by right-clicking on the Desktop and following the prompts to run `$HOME/bin/thing` in a Terminal or you can create the file manually:

```
cat <<'X' >"$HOME/Desktop/Thing.desktop"
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=true
Name=Thing
Exec=bin/thing
Type=Application
X
```

(You could substitute `Exec=.local/bin/thing` if appropriate.)