# Install coccigrep on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pip

Coccigrep (https://pypi.org/project/coccigrep/) seems to be a great tool to search through C code.
However, when I install it using `pip install coccigrep`, it isn't found:

```
> coccigrep
coccigrep: command not found
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.
How do I install this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a `$PATH` related issue(message: command not found). `pip` must be installing things on `~/.local/bin` or `~/bin`, the bin directories inside your home.

You will have to add that location by editing the `.profile` file inside your home, and adding the following line at the end of that file:

`PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

After that, `source ~/.profile` should be enough to reload your profile file.

Take a look at the Bug #1588562 link below. It should be fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 but there is a guy reporting that it's not.

**Related Stuff:**

- [Which distributions have $HOME/.local/bin in $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316765/34720)
- [Correcting path setting in ~/.profile file](https://askubuntu.com/q/984047/494660)
- [Bug #1588562 - Please add ~/.local/bin to the default $PATH](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1588562)