# Adding command shortcuts to /bin

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, docker

Is there any way to add custom commands to `/bin`?

For example, I use `docker container ls` a lot, and would like to turn this into a shortcut command, like `dcls`.

If I add a file named `dcls` to `/bin` and inside the file, specify the exact command `docker container ls`, I assume this wouldn't work.

What is the right way, if there is one, to do something like this?

Comment: Don't add to `/bin`, you can add to `~/bin` (a bin in your own directory), or to `/usr/local/bin` (to share with all users of your system, but not interfere with package manager). Or better in this case, to use an alias.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An easy way for a shortcut is to define an `alias`

```
alias dcls='docker container ls'
```

This will execute `docker container ls` when you enter `dcls` and the command `alias` lists your defined aliases. To remove this alias use `unalias dcls`.

If you use bash, you can save the alias in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

If your `~/.bash_aliases` is not read on startup, you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy! Will I have to create this alias every time the server restarts? Or is it bounded to my user profile?

Comment: You have to save it in your user's shell startup file `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or ... If you don't save the alias it is lost when you logout or close the terminal.

Comment: Thanks again. What if we dont have .bashrc or .profile in our ~ folder?

Comment: Really? What an odd server! If you use bash, you can create it using `echo "alias dcls='docker container ls'" >> ~/.bashrc`, then source it with `. ~/.bashrc` or logout and login again.

Comment: Cheers for your help, got it working!

Answer (score 17):

Actually, what you describe would work, with a few notes:

1. You could simply put `docker container ls` into a file called `/bin/dcls`. 
   But the behavior of that can be a little complicated. 
   It’s a little more reliable to begin the file with a line called a “shebang”,
   so the file would look like

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   docker container ls
   ```

   which specifies that the file is a shell script.
2. Before you can run the command,
   you must make the file executable with a command like

   ```
   chmod +x /bin/dcls
   ```

   You probably need to be root to do this (i.e., run it with `sudo`).
3. Follow the above two steps and you will be able to type `dcls`
   and it will do `docker container ls`.
   But, if you type `dcls -l foo`, it will still do `docker container ls`. 
   If you want it to do `docker container ls -l foo`,
   you should change the script to say

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   docker container ls "$@"
   ```

   which specifies that any arguments that you type on the `dcls` command line
   should be passed along to the `docker container ls` command.

   Naturally, there are more complicated things
   you can do with command-line arguments.

For a mapping of one simple command → one simple command,
that doesn’t need to be shared with other users,
it’s simpler to define an alias ([as Freddy suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516870/23408#516871)),
or a shell function. 
More complicated functions are often written as scripts;
i.e., text files that contain commands. 
But, if you don’t need to share it with other users,
it’s more common to use a private `bin` directory.

```
$ cd                                    # (to your home directory)
$ mkdir bin
```

Then copy `dcls` to `$HOME/bin`,
and add

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

to your `~/.bashrc`.

Also, it’s common to put personal scripts into `/usr/local/bin`,
and leave `/bin` for the programs that came with the system.

Comment: Great answer. If I add it to bin like I mentioned, that would affect all users correct?

Comment: Yes; all users look in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and typically shared directories like `/usr/local/bin` and sometimes `/opt`, so programs in those directories are available to all users.

Comment: If you want to share with others on you system use `/usr/local/bin` so it does not interfere with package manager.

Comment: +1 for recommending ``$HOME/bin``. You should really use this. This is not only the right scope, but helps when you reinstall your system (and keep your ``HOME``) not to lose your custom command.

Comment: I prefer this over alias because sooner or later you would want write a command longer than 1 line. Also, the command can be implemented using a language other than shell.

Comment: FWIW I use `~/.local/bin` [instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316765/18887).

Comment: Save one PID by prepending the command with `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

If just for you, an alias is fine but according to the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) local system-wide scripts go in `/usr/local/bin/`, not `/bin`.

1. Although it would certainly work in `/bin`, it's better to keep to standards especially if your software is going to be deployed at customer's sites.
2. If your script would be optional, it should go in `/opt`
3. The script itself would be:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # Version 1.0 DD 2019-05-04
   # dcls = docker container ls
   docker container ls "@0"
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
     echo -e "Errors encountered..."
     exit 1
   fi
   ```