# Maintenance script location

Tags: filesystems, filenames

I have a bunch of maintenance scripts that are typically only run by cron or root.  I had been putting them in `/usr/local/sbin` but honestly, I don't want them in the path.  Normal users can't (and don't want to) run them and even root doesn't need them in the path.  There are several other options, but I'm not sure which is best.

Considerations:

- `/root/maintenance` - Reservation is that not all maintenance scripts run as root.
- `/opt/maintenance` - Guess it is an optional package.
- `/usr/local/maintenance` - If placing sub-directories in `/usr/local` isn't unorthodox.
- `/etc/maintenance` - Doesn't seem like a configuration, but there are other scripts are in `/etc`.

While I understand I *can* put the maintenance scripts wherever I like, I'd prefer to place them in standard location.  If there isn't one, a sensible location will do.

Comment: Should we assume a Linux system or some other *nix?

Comment: @terdon I only use Linux, but the more portable the solution, the better.

Comment: @roaima Do you have a reference you can cite for this style, or is this just a convention you use?

Answer (score 2):

I've used directories under `/usr/local` for a good number of years. Possibly from as far back as [SVR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V#SVR3) but it might have been [BSDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Design).

In this case, where there are a number of scripts grouped together as *maintentance* related tasks, I'd consider `/usr/local/maintenance/bin` with related configuration files in /usr/local/maintenance/etc. In my case such directories would typically be accessible by all users - not just `root` - but again that would be down to specific requirements.

Formalised in [FHS 3.0 section 4.9.1](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html), and then broken by me with section 4.9.2.

I've noticed that some people quite like the similar approach using `/opt/{whatever}/bin`. No significant difference as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, I do see that in section 4.9.2 it states "No other directories, except those listed below, may be in /usr/local after first installing a FHS-compliant system."  While I like the `/usr/local/maintenance/bin` path better, it does sound like `/opt/maintenance/bin` is FHS compliant.  Thank you.

Comment: @A.Que it's your system

Answer (score -1):

The following look to be quite common:

```
/root/bin

/root/.local/bin
```

though these might be more convention than anything else.

Comment: Are they? Have you seen this sort of scheme outside Ubuntu? As far as I know (but I may very well be wrong) the `~/bin` thing is an Ubuntu convention.

Comment: Could be, but better stolen than badly create your own stuff. If it's Ubuntu, it might be Debian... See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316765/44864 for more.

Comment: That is about `~/.local/bin` not `~/bin`. And putting scripts (i.e. non-binary files) in `bin` directories seems a little odd. Not very, mind you, just a little. Anyway, I was just wondering about your claim that these are common since I do not believe they are. Not my downvote, by the way for what it's worth.

Comment: /usr/local/bin contains a _lot_ of scripts on a lot of systems ;-)

Comment: My only concern with this set option is that not all maintenance cron jobs run as root.  They might be launched by root, but run as some less privileged user.  Could you provide a reference for this convention?

Comment: That's it: a convention, a habit. No hard government backed law.

Comment: @A.Que frankly I don't think it is a convention at all but instead a choice made by either just one or a small group of specifically Linux systems. It certainly isn't a broad, *nix convention and not even particularly common in the Linux world.

Comment: @terdon One CentOS 7 server I have has over 800 shell scripts in `/usr/bin`. Debian isn't much better. Scripts include GNU utilities so they might be somewhat ubiquitous. `/bin/true` was a shell script on SunOS 4.1.3 as an older example.

Comment: @doneal24 yes, hence the "Not very, mind you, just a little". Nothing wrong with putting scripts in `bin` directories, just slightly surprising to create a non-standard location for non-binary files and call that `bin`. But only _slightly_.

Comment: @terdon Yes, but `/usr/local/exe/` looks odd on a *ix system.