# What to do when .profile does not exist for editing PATH?

Tags: environment-variables, path, profile

I want to edit my `$PATH` environment variable. According to several tutorials and other sources (e.g. this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux)), the most common way is to edit `~/.profile`. However, for me, no such file exists. What can I do? (Are there different names on some systems? Should I create it? What needs to go in there? Are there other ways?)

I am a user on a network cluster, obviously I don't want to edit any global environment variables. I've edited `~/.bashrc` before to change some stuff for my user, and there are several `~/.`-files, but not `~/.profile`.

*I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Codename: Xenial. `echo $PATH` gives me only some global bin-directories, but after installing some user specific bins (to `/path/to/home~/expanded/.local/bin/`) I just want to add this to the PATH.*

Comment: A  `.local` (a *hidden* directory) in your `$PATH` is poor taste IMHO. Better use `$HOME/bin` which might even be "automatically" added on some distributions (but you need to login again)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370943/how-did-the-local-bin-thing-start-how-widespread-is-it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for your advice. As the excellent pointer from Kusalananda suggests, I'm setting up python which uses `.local/bin` by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `~/.bash_profile` file, then edit that instead (since you seems to be using `bash` (since you are on Linux and since you mention that there is a `~/.bashrc` file present that you've edited before)).  The `bash` shell will only try to read `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` does not exist. If neither file exists, you may create `~/.bash_profile`.

The line you are likely to want to add is

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

or

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

depending on whether you want/need the added directory to be searched first or last.

There is no need for `export` as the `PATH` variable is already exported.

`$HOME` is the same as `~`, but is IMHO more expressive in shell scripts. It also behaves as a proper variable whereas `~` does not.  See e.g. [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)

Also note that paths are delimited with forward slash (`/`) on Unix, not backslash (`\`), so you want `~/.bash_profile` and not `~\.bash_profile`.

---

Most `sh`-like shells (of which `bash` is one) reads `.profile` in the user's home directory when started as a login shell.  This is why the answer that you linked to mentions `.profile` rather than `.bash_profile`; the specific shell used was not mentioned in the question.

Some shells, like `bash`, will ignore it if their own special startup file is present.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer. I corrected the backslashes to forward-slashes in the paths. Bad habit back from using Windows.