# Makefile - How to install a bash script into user's bin directory?

Tags: shell-script, directory, make

I need to make a Makefile to install a bash script into a user's `bin` directory, but I'm not sure what the best way of doing this would be. Should I be using a variable that accepts user input to specify their bin directory's location, or is there an environment variable for this (at least in most distros)?

Comment: Related - [How did the ~/.local/bin thing start? How widespread is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370943/100397). And I'm with the poster - `$HOME/bin` for me, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general a user may not have a bin directory. A Makefile like this allows you to say `make DESTDIR=/usr/local/bin install` to install to /usr/local/bin, and a default to ~/bin

```
# DESTDIR is where the program should be installed
DESTDIR = $$HOME/bin
prog: a.c b.c
      ${CC} -o $@ $<
install: prog
      mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}
      cp $< ${DESTDIR}
```

this makes the program from a couple of C file. The `install` target creates the bin directory if it doesn't exist (the -p stops it erroring out if it does exist) and then copies the file. Note the `$$` on the shell variables.

GNU make would allow an `order only prerequisite` to only create the directory if it didn't exist, but the time to run mkdir is likely small compared to the time to do the compiles.